# How to know that $2n^3+9n^2+13n+6$ factors into $(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Apologies in advance, my math is very rusty.

I'm slowly working my way through Schaum's Outline of Discrete Math for some self-study, occasionally filling in large knowledge gaps in my grasp on algebra. In one of the supplementary questions I'm asked to prove (by induction) that:

$$
\sum^n_{i=1}i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$

In the inductive step I add $(n+1)^2$ to either side and then try to work my way through, multiplying out the factors:

$$
\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + (n+1)^2 \\
= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)+6(n+1)^2}{6} \\
= \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)+6(n+1)^2}{6} \\
= \frac{2n^3+n^2+2n^2+n+6(n^2+2n+1)}{6} \\
= \frac{2n^3+n^2+2n^2+n+6n^2+12n+6}{6} \\
= \frac{2n^3+9n^2+13n+6}{6}
$$

I think everything up to this point is pretty trivial, but it's around this point that I get a bit lost. I know I need to factor the terms in the 3-degree polynomial in the numerator somehow, but I'm having a hard time with the actual mechanics given the lack of obvious common factors & the fact that 13 is prime.

I'm pretty sure the final result should look something like:

$$
\frac{(n+1)((n+1)+1)(2(n+1)+1)}{6} \\
= \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)}{6}
$$

Multiplying the expected result out I can see the two statements are equal and I'm confident that

$$
\frac{2n^3+9n^2+13n+6}{6} = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)}{6}
$$

but I'm just not quite sure how to factor the polynomial myself to arrive at the final result.

Any hints on how to proceed from here, or what I need to be reading up on to get my head around this?

Comment: You pretty-much proceed by trial and error. Note that the middle coefficients aren't as helpful as the ends. If there are going to be "nice" factors, they'll need to look like $$(\text{factor of } 2) n \pm (\text{factor of } 6)$$ (You can rule-out possibilities like $2n\pm 2$ and $2n\pm 6$, as these have factors of $2$ that the full polynomial lacks.) To test what works, you can try clever grouping, or you can observe that $a n + b$ is a *factor* if $-b/a$ is a *root* (a value of $n$ that makes the polynomial become $0$). Since $2(-1)^3+9(-1)^2+13(-1)+6=0$, we know that $n-(-1)$ is a factor.

Comment: It's worth noting that technology can handle this stuff for you. For instance, you can use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5B2n%5E3%2B9n%5E2%2B13n%2B6%5D) to perform the factorization.

Comment: Had no idea Wolfram Alpha could do that -- going to be helpful for checking my own working. Thanks a ton!

Comment: WolframAlpha is essentially an online version of *Mathematica*, which is serious mathematical software. It can do pretty much anything. It easily does stuff like [the summation that triggered your question](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%5Bk%5E2,k%3D1...n%5D). (Disclaimer: I'm not associated with Wolfram. I'm just a fan and a customer.)

Comment: Assumed as much. :) My first thought on seeing your link was "I wonder if I can do this with R?". Cool stuff.

Comment: Probably the best way to do it is to use the rational root theorem like @Blue says. There are some more clever and cool answers in the comments, but really for the everyday drudgery like this it's easiest to just use the theorem; now if THAT doesn't work, then I would start looking other ways. But textbooks don't expect you to know tricks like Chief VOLDERMORT's for example, any polynomial of degree $\ge3$ that comes up should be factoriable either using the rational root theorem or by simple grouping.

Comment: Agreed @Ovi. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) tells you that any rational root of the polynomial $2 n^3 + 9 n^2 + 13 n + 6$ has the form $\frac{p}{q}$ for integers $q \mid 2$, $p \mid 6$, leaving 12 possible rational roots. Since all of the coefficients are positive, all of the (real) roots are negative, leaving only 6 possible rational roots, $-6, -3, -2, -\frac{3}{2}, -1, -\frac{1}{2}$.

Substituting, for example, $-1$ (because it's fast to evaluate a polynomial at $-1$---just take the alternating sum of the coefficients) gives $-2 + 9 - 13  + 6 = 0$, so $n = -1$ is a root of the polynomial, and equivalently the polynomial has factor $n + 1$. Dividing the polynomial by $n + 1$ and factoring gives $2 n^2 + 7 n + 6 = (n + 2)(2 n + 3)$, and putting this all together gives the desired factorization:
$$\boxed{2 n^3 + 9 n^2 + 13 n + 6 = (n + 1) (n + 2) (2 n + 3)}.$$

**Remark** As you probably know, not all polynomials with integer coefficients factor into products of linear terms with integer coefficients as they did in this case. For example, the general formula for $\sum i^4$ analogous to the one in this question contains a factor of $3 n^2 + 3 n - 1$, which is not factorable over the integers.

Comment: One point of clarification: "Expanding the right-hand side and comparing like terms in n quickly gives that a=2,b=7,c=6" ... so e.g. $an^2(n+1)+bn(n+1)+c(n+1)$ then somehow we can work back to values of a, b and c? I'll have to try that. The tip RE: finding zeros easily for -1 is also something I think I would have missed. The rational root theorem is something I know I'm going to find valuable too. Thanks for all of this, super helpful as a starting point for further understanding where I went wrong here.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful. If you ask a follow-up question, feel free to post the link as a reply to my answer, and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: And yes, that's exactly what I mean by comparing like terms. Expanding and collecting terms by powers then gives $$a n^3 + (a + b) n^2 + (b + c) n + c = 2 n^3 + 9 n^2 + 13 n + 6 .$$ Now, two polynomials agree if and only each of their coefficients agrees, so we have $$a = 2, \quad a + b = 9, \quad b + c = 13, \quad c = 6 .$$ Substituting the first equation into the second, for example, recovers $b = 7$ like we wanted. There's trick/observation, by the way, for checking whether $1$ is a root of a polynomial similar to that for $-1$.

Comment: Hm I think I'll probably end up using something like synthetic division using roots for now until I get a little more comfortable with the mechanics. Still appreciate all the insight here. Accepted your answer, thanks again!

Comment: I assume you meant to write $p/q$ rather than $p, q$ in your first sentence.

Comment: @mathimpaired Synthetic division is efficient, too---the relevant algebra is basically equivalent to solving the equations in the latter display equation from left to right.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig You're right, of course, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 4):

Recall (in your question) the line ...
$$=\frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)+6(n+1)^2}{6}$$

What followed, however was a missed opportunity, for $n^2+n$ factors as $n(n+1)$, so your expression becomes
$$\begin{align}
\frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)+6(n+1)^2}{6} &= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)+6(n+1)^2}{6}\\
&= \frac{(n+1)\bigg(n(2n+1)+6(n+1)\bigg)}{6}\\
&= \frac{(n+1)(2n^2+n+6n+6)}{6}\\
&= \frac{(n+1)(2n^2+7n+6)}{6}\\
\end{align}
$$
and all that remains to do is to factor the quadratic $2n^2+7n+6$, and you're done. :-)

Comment: D'oh, you're absolutely right! I just accepted Travis' answer because it's a more general solution & there were a number of "missing links" in there that I wouldn't have figured out on my own without a lot more reading. Also, I can't trust myself to "see" the kind of thing that you just pointed out here. But I was also very much hoping somebody would point out something like this! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Find a single root of the polynomial through trial and error and then apply long division. Dividing $(2n^3+9n^2+13n+6)$ by $(n+1)$ yields $(n+2)(2n+3)=2n^2+7n+6$.
A root of $-1$ yields a factor of $(n+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Step-by-step simplification
$$2n^3 + 9n^2+13n+6$$ $$= 2n(n^2 + 4n + 4) + (n^2+5n+6)$$$$=2n(n+2)^2+(n+2)(n+3)$$$$=(n+2)(n+3+2n(n+2))$$$$=(n+2)(n+3+2n^2+4n)$$$$=(n+2)(2n^2+5n+3)$$$$=(n+2)(2n(n+1) + 3(n+1))$$$$ = (n+2)(n+1)(2n+3)$$

Comment: last line mistake.

Comment: Thans @TakahiroWaki

Comment: I think I can mostly follow this, but how did you "know" to pull out $n^2 + 5n + 6$ specifically in your first step? I tried similar approaches, but they typically led me to dead ends. Wondering if I'm missing some key/"obvious" insight here.

Comment: My personal approach to factorise polynomials of 3degree(power) or more is to take out such power of x that we have a square term left. for example from power of three we take common a single. As to having $$n^2 + 5n + 6$$ it was left after taking $$8n^2+8n$$ for left side term. I was trying to convert the left side term into something factorisable preferably a square.

Comment: You will start to "know" the steps after a certain amount of practise

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

You should have factored $(n+1)$ at your first numerator and factor the resulting quadratic easily.

Even at this point where you have a cubic you have $x=-1$ as a candidate so divide the cubic by $(x+1) $ and factor the resulting quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

put $n=-1,-2$, and get $0$. Then this equation has factor $(n+1)(n+2)$.